# remove string characters from the parameters of the nested resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have nested resources in my form, in one of them I have a field called "value_paid" that has a structure like the following: "$ 2", but because my value_paid field is of decimal type in the database, I need that at the time of saving the fields, only save the numerical characters of all the nested resources in the value_paid fields

I am applying this same type of validation but for a main field, it would be this:

```
def payment_params
  final_params = params.require(:payment).permit(:payment, :day, :comments, :billing_id, payment_details_attributes: [:id, :value_paid, :voucher, :date_voucher, :observation, :payment_method_id, :payment_id, :paid_destination, :_destroy])
  final_params['payment'] = final_params['payment'].scan(/[.0-9]/).join().to_f
  final_params
end
```

how do I apply it to each value_paid fields of the nested attributes payment_details_attributes ?

Comment: Make changes in your form to take only integer value or else you can write before_save callback in child model to modify the value will solve your problem.

Comment: Instead of before_save I would suggest to use before_validation callback. Because as the field is integer so there must be numericality validations for it.

Answer (score 0):

I would add a custom setter method to the model and sanitize the input in the model.

```
# in app/model/payment.rb
def payment=(value)
  value = value.scan(/[\d\.,]*/).join if value.is_a?(String)

  super(value)
end
```